# Object bait for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have this situation. After the line `c = null;` in Example's `main` method, will the `Collar` object be bait for Garbage collection ?

**`Example.java`** is :

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Collar c = new Collar();
        Kit k = new Kit(c);
        c = null;
        //more code to keep the program running

    }
}
```

**`Kit.java`** is :

```
class Kit{    
    Collar kit_col;
    public Kit(Collar col){
        kit_col = col;
    }
}
```

**`Collar.java`** is :

```
class Collar{
    public Collar(){
        //nothing here
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `Kit` still refers to your `Collar` object, no. Until `k` goes out of scope, that instance of `Kit` is visible, therefore the `Collar` instance it references is visible too. Objects are only collected when there is no reasonable way to access them.

Comment: @biziclop, imagine a case where there are no references to an object at all, but the object in question has a lot of reference to other objects. Can it be GCed then ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to your `Kit` instance, and the `Kit` instance has a reference to your `Collar` instance, then **neither one** can be garbage collected. You still essentially have references to both.

Comment: This has to do with `passing by value is passing by copy`, right ? The variable `c` and `kit_col` aren't tied together in any way other than just pointing to the same object on the heap. True?